how to interpret the "its broadest reasonable interpretation" under 35 U.S.C. 102
The examiner use part of the drawing to state that inventor anticipation, and has listed ALL my claims elements, but the prior art has no any words that either expressly or inherently described in description, I assume this is the examiner authority to do so, but not sure

List item should the examiner anticipate ALL the elements in his 1st report? or he can just add the element that he didn't notice, certainly the prior art never anticipated it later when I point out some missing element in his report?
List item is it reasonable that he/inventor anticipate a long flat strap into an irregular angle strap like below picture? angled shape was mentioned in the description, but the examiner didn't notice it, I mean he/inventor never want this angled strap but could he still use his broadest reasonable interpretation AGAIN?
List item should I explicitly specify ALL elements in my claims, or as long as it is inclusive, it can be in description to define something, that not as common knowledge?
List item I think it's inappropriate and impolite to argue his anticipation, and I will amend my claims, I am concerned he use his broadest reasonable interpretation AGAIN


highly appreciated for any input or advice.

Rejections are extremely common. Some times the examiner is just being lazy and wants  you to educate them. Arguing a rejection is expected and not impolite so long as you do so politely.

Hi @Erics Thank you for your input, I have to say that many variation of the invention was not mentioned or maybe figured out by the examiner,  is this means I DID write the description very clearly? I learned that only ONE embodiment is fine for application? I have a lot of different shapes, and specify " can not be only square" is this enough? have a nice start of the week.

Comments are not the place for new questions. Better to ask a new question.


I assume this is the examiner authority to do so, but not sure

Never assume the examiner is right. They may be, but often they are not. The trouble is, it's not enough to state that they are wrong, you have to diagnose the problem and fight it correctly and accurately.

should the examiner anticipate ALL the elements in his 1st report? or he can just add the element that he didn't notice

The examiner is free to fill in details in the rejection or even change tacks at any time. Sometimes it may constitute a new ground of rejection but the only consequence there is that the rejection cannot be made final.

reasonable that he/inventor anticipate a long flat strap into an irregular angle strap like below picture? angled shape was mentioned in the description, but the examiner didn't notice it, I mean he/inventor never want this angled strap but could he still use his broadest reasonable interpretation AGAIN?

If angled is only mentioned in the prior art but not in your claim and specification, then the problem may be that the strap as claimed is not exclusive of being angled as well. If you explicitly wrote "flat" in the claim, then you may have a point here. There is no way that the BRI of flat includes angled. However if "flat" appears only in your specification and not in your claim, you may have less of a point.

I explicitly specify ALL elements in my claims, or as long as it is inclusive, it can be in description to define something, that not as common knowledge?

I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think the examiner can use "common knowledge" to fill in gaps in an anticipation rejection. If there are gaps where the person of ordinary skill needs to make adjustments or substitutions that should be a 103 already.

I think it's inappropriate and impolite to argue his anticipation, and I will amend my claims, I am concerned he use his broadest reasonable interpretation AGAIN

If you believe the anticipation is improper, the best strategy is to fight the rejection (but politely of course). Caving when the examiner is wrong is not a good strategy for precisely the reason you're stating.

Hi @bhuff36, I hope you are doing well, thank you for your help as always, I DIDN'T state the angled strap in my claims, but I DID specify** the strap is not limited to be flat** in the description. I don't think the examiner noticed it or figure out how to work in a angled strap. in this scenario, will the patent be protected by the law when there is infringement in the future? or I have to specify it, the issue here is too many variation in the invention. what do you think?
